# Rendering an email throws a TemplateCompilationException using RazorEngine 3 in a non-MVC project

Tags: razor, template-engine, razor-2

I am trying to render emails in a windows service host.

I use RazorEngine 3 forked by coxp which has support for Razor 2.
https://github.com/coxp/RazorEngine/tree/release-3.0/src

This works fine for a couple of emailtemplates but there is one causing me problems.

```
@model string

<a href="@Model" target="_blank">Click here</a> to enter a new password for your account.
```

This throws a CompilationException: The name 'WriteAttribute' does not exist in the current context. So passing in a string as model and putting it in the href-attribute causes problems.

I can make it work by changing this line by:

```
@Raw(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"_blank\">Klik hier</a>.", @Model))
```

but this makes the template very unreadable and harder to pass along to a marketing department for further styling.

I like to add that referencing the RazorEngine by using a Nuget package is not a solution since it is based on Razor 1 and somewhere along the process the DLL for system.web.razor gets replaced by version 2 which breaks any code using RazorEngine. It seems more interesting to use Razor 2 to benefit from the new features and to be up to date.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be great. Sharing your experiences is also very welcome.

UPDATE 1

It seems like calling SetTemplateBaseType might help, but this method does not exist anymore, so I wonder how to be able to bind the templatebasetype?

```
//Missing method in the new RazorEngine build from coxp.
Razor.SetTemplateBaseType(typeof(HtmlTemplateBase<>));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Windsor to inject the template service rather than using the Razor object. Here is a simplified part of the code that shows how to set the base template type.

```
    private static ITemplateService CreateTemplateService()
    {
        var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
                         {
                             BaseTemplateType = typeof (HtmlTemplateBase<>),
                         };
        return new TemplateService(config);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RazorEngine 3.1.0

Little bit modified example based on **coxp** answer without the injection:

```
    private static bool _razorInitialized;

    private static void InitializeRazor()
    {
        if (_razorInitialized) return;
        _razorInitialized = true;
        Razor.SetTemplateService(CreateTemplateService());
    }

    private static ITemplateService CreateTemplateService()
    {
        var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
            {
                BaseTemplateType = typeof (HtmlTemplateBase<>),
            };
        return new TemplateService(config);
    }

    public static string ParseTemplate(string name, object model)
    {
        InitializeRazor();

        var appFileName = "~/EmailTemplates/" + name + ".cshtml";
        var template = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(appFileName));
        return RazorEngine.Razor.Parse(template, model);
    }
```