# How to Insert a URL into an anchor href ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a razor email template. My goal is to insert a url into an anchor but when I insert the html I am presented with an error `The name 'WriteAttribute' does not exist in the current context`

My code is very simple.

Context Property

```
public string _Domain { get; set; }
```

Email.Cshtml

```
....
@(model._Domain)
....
```

This code above correctly shows the string value of the domain `http://www.MyTestSite.com`

But the moment I put that value into an anchor href, I'm presented with the error above.

```
<a href="@(model._Domain)"> Click Here <a/>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. If I replace `href="@(model._Domain)"` with `href="http://www.MyTestSite.com"`, then it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering an email throws a TemplateCompilationException using RazorEngine 3 in a non-MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136275/rendering-an-email-throws-a-templatecompilationexception-using-razorengine-3-in)

Answer (score 0):

I think above solution will work, if it is not worked,
Try to load the @model._domain value in to the variable and assign it to the anchor  by using the id. on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")#features">Features</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code , `<a href="@Model._Domain">Click Here</a>`.

If your url is an action in your controllers use
@Url.Action

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code; just post the code itself, instead.